# How to parse JSON to Objects in Android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have some JSON data as shown below:

```
{
    "pp": {
        "status_marital_pmg": "BELUM MENIKAH",
        "nama_pmg": "IWEN LENDER",
        "kerjab_pmg": "-",
        "pendidikan_pmg": "S1",
        "agama_pmg": "KRISTEN KATOLIK",
        "bidang_industri_pmg": "JASA KEUANGAN",
        "warga_pmg": "INDONESIA",
        "hubungan_pmg_ttg": "Diri Sendiri",
        "pendanaana_pmg": "GAJI",
        "pendanaan_pmg": "GAJI",
        "usia_pmg": 33,
        "penghasilan_pmg": "> RP. 50 JUTA - RP. 100 JUTA",
        "kelamin_pmg": "Pria",
        "tujuan_pmg": "INVESTASI",
        "tujuana_pmg": "INVESTASI",
        "kerja_pmg": "KARYAWAN",
        "bidang_industria_pmg": "JASAKEUANGAN"
    }
}
```

I am trying to map this JSON using the following class:

```
public class VariabelViewer {
    private String nama_pmg;
    private String pendidikan_pmg;
    private String warga_pmg;
    private String usia_pmg;
    private String status_marital_pmg;
    private String kelamin_pmg;
    private String agama_pmg;
    private String tujuan_pmg;
    private String tujuana_pmg;
    private String penghasilan_pmg;
    private String pendanaan_pmg;
    private String pendanaana_pmg;
    private String bidang_industria_pmg;
    private String hubungan_pmg_ttg;

    public VariabelViewer(String nama_pmg, String pendidikan_pmg,
            String warga_pmg, String usia_pmg, String status_marital_pmg,
            String kelamin_pmg, String agama_pmg, String tujuan_pmg,
            String tujuana_pmg, String penghasilan_pmg, String pendanaan_pmg,
            String pendanaana_pmg, String bidang_industria_pmg,
            String hubungan_pmg_ttg) {

        this.nama_pmg = nama_pmg;
        this.pendidikan_pmg = pendidikan_pmg;
        this.warga_pmg = warga_pmg;
        this.usia_pmg = usia_pmg;
        this.status_marital_pmg = status_marital_pmg;
        this.kelamin_pmg = kelamin_pmg;
        this.agama_pmg = agama_pmg;
        this.tujuan_pmg = tujuan_pmg;
        this.tujuana_pmg = tujuana_pmg;
        this.penghasilan_pmg = penghasilan_pmg;
        this.pendanaan_pmg = pendanaan_pmg;
        this.pendanaana_pmg = pendanaana_pmg;
        this.bidang_industria_pmg = bidang_industria_pmg;
        this.hubungan_pmg_ttg = hubungan_pmg_ttg;
    }

    public String getNama_pmg() {
        return nama_pmg;
    }

    public String getPendidikan_pmg() {
        return pendidikan_pmg;
    }

    public String getWarga_pmg() {
        return warga_pmg;
    }

    public String getUsia_pmg() {
        return usia_pmg;
    }

    public String getStatus_marital_pmg() {
        return status_marital_pmg;
    }

    public String getKelamin_pmg() {
        return kelamin_pmg;
    }

    public String getAgama_pmg() {
        return agama_pmg;
    }

    public String getTujuan_pmg() {
        return tujuan_pmg;
    }

    public String getTujuana_pmg() {
        return tujuana_pmg;
    }

    public String getPenghasilan_pmg() {
        return penghasilan_pmg;
    }

    public String getPendanaan_pmg() {
        return pendanaan_pmg;
    }

    public String getPendanaana_pmg() {
        return pendanaana_pmg;
    }

    public String getBidangindustria_pmg() {
        return bidang_industria_pmg;
    }

    public String getHubungan_pmg_ttg() {
        return hubungan_pmg_ttg;
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to go about actually declaring the right classes in my code and parsing the data. I think my JSON represents a JSON Array that contain another JSON array too, but my understanding could be wrong? Can anyone show me how to parse this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
            JSONObject jsobj = new JSONObject("your string goes here");
            JSONObject ppobj = jsobj.getJSONObject("pp");
            String status_marital_pmg = ppobj.getString("status_marital_pmg");
            Integer usia_pmg = ppobj.getInt("usia_pmg");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
```

Comment: how about my class VariabelViewer that i have made before..? is it doesn't use?

Comment: well, you can add constructor or method to it that will take JSONObject as a parameter and do parsing there.

Answer (score 2):

> think my JSON is JSON Array that contain JSON Array too, is my
>   understanding wrong?

Yes you are wrong, because current Json String contains only JSONObject's instead of JSONArray. so you will need to first convert current string as JSONObject and then extract all objects from it as :

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(<current json string>);

// get all key names from JSONObject
JSONArray allnames=json.names();

for(int i=0;i<allnames.length;i++){

  JSONObject jsonobj=json.getJSONObject(allnames[i]);

  // get all values from inner JSONObject and store in any data structure 
  //get status_marital_pmg
  String str_status_marital_pmg=jsonobj.optString("status_marital_pmg");
  ....

}
```

Comment: how about my class VariabelViewer that i have made before..? is it doesn't use?

Comment: @AoyamaNanami : you can use VariabelViewer class as getter/setter

Comment: @AoyamaNanami : you will need to create an ArrayList of type VariabelViewer and ten create an object of VariabelViewer by passing all values from jsonobject then store it in ArrayList for further use

Comment: i don't get it... what about my "pp"?

Comment: is my VariabelViewer class for declare my json,true?

Comment: @AoyamaNanami : "pp" is object name which u can get in JSONarray using `JSONArray allnames=json.names();` for Iterating using for loop